# Python - Print text (html) starting from position

Tags: python

I'm trying to search a word (ie. meta) from a html text and print the following 20 characters starting from the position of that word.

The following code doesn't return anything:

```
import os,sys,urllib.request
url = "http://www.google.com/"
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
html2 = html.decode("windows-1252")
b2='meta'
position=html2.index(b2)
if b2 in html2:
    print(html2[position:20])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to:

```
print(html2[position: position + 20])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(html2[position : position + 20])` at the last line.